# Show javascript alert with VBA

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vba, excel

I have managed to open IE via excel and navigate with it, but i am not able to run basic JS functions like "alert" or "prompt". (in browser, not MsgBox in excel)
I have tried:

```
appIE.document.onLoad = "function() { alert(""text"");};"
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can only attach that handler to an existing document, which by definition has *already* loaded, so you're not going to see an alert from that. Have you tried attaching an event to an element in the document after it has loaded? I think also that last semi-colon is not required.

Comment: This was the only solution i could think of, is there any way i could show an alert on the webpage instead of excel? (regardless if it is an event or not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
appIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "alert('text');", "jscript"
```